# What is the phrase represented by this rebus?

Tags: rebus

[image]

For those who don't know, a rebus is where words are represented by a picture and you try to figure what word or phrase the picture is trying to represent.

> What is the phrase above?

Comment: Nice type puzzle! Endless possibilities; I’m taking a note of this one ;)

Comment: I agree. Nice and simple. Keep designing these @UnidentifiedX

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I think the phrase might be

> Holy Water

Explanation

> $H_2O$ represents water and it appears to be full of holes (hole-y)

Comment: For a fun time visit the beautiful Lake District in the north-west of England. You might enjoy the quaint dry stone walls frequently to be seen there. When the stones are laid at an angle to prevent water penetrating the wall, it is called a water-shot. So close...

Comment: It's an interesting font.

Answer (score 13):

Is it:

> [Watering holes](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/watering+hole) (places where animals gather to drink). Lots of holes surrounded by water.

Answer (score 10):

Might be a stretch, but what about:

> Soda/Seltzer Water?

Because:

> H2O obviously means water, but in this case it is water with bubbles in it?

Answer (score 7):

The phrase is

> Navy / Fleet

Explanation

> The rebus shows holes in h2o, which is water. It is well known that [a boat is a hole in the water](https://www.barrypopik.com/index.php/new_york_city/entry/a_boat_is_a_hole_in_the_water_into_which_you_pour_money/), so multiple holes would mean multiple boats: either a fleet or a navy.

Comment: Did you just post this because of my comment on JMP's answer?

Comment: Nope but it’s a good third option!

Answer (score 4):

Another answer

> without involving water: is that a [stream cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher)?

Because

> The bubbles indicate flowing (i.e. a *stream*), while the "H2O" part, reading as "H to O", means "(translate) a letter to another letter", i.e. substitution *cipher*.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

> light water (opposite of *heavy water*)

because

> the "holes" in the *water* remove weight.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be:

> Evaporating Water or Water Evaporation

As:

> The rebus gives off the effect that it is disappearing or changing states.

Answer (score 0):

> Bubbly water? Another alternative would be airbubbles / bubbles of air

Answer (score 0):

Other possible answers:

> Coconut Water - Coconut-shaped cut-outs on the water

And

> Can't Hold Water - The word H20 wouldn't be able to *hold water* because it has holes in it