# More rebus puzzles

Tags: rebus

Yet another rebus. I have a feeling this one will go quick.
[image: lLobe]

What is this picture trying to say?

*Edit: @Hugh solved this quickly so I'm adding two more that I imagine are a little more cryptic but still in the spirit of rebus puzzles.*

*Edit2: Modified #2 and #3 to be clearer.*

#2
[image: We're]

#3
[image: DDevil]

In @UnidentifiedX's [words](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94216/what-is-the-phrase-represented-by-this-rebus), `For those who don't know, a rebus is where words are represented by a picture and you try to figure what word or phrase the picture is trying to represent.`

Comment: Is #3 rot13(qrzbargvfngvba)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*The later two puzzles were edited in after the posting of this answer.*

I believe that the solution to the rebus puzzle is:

> **Lo and behold**, as "*Lo*" and "*be*" are *hold*ing hands.

Comment: Nice, probably too easy so I just edited in two more!

Answer (score 3):

So, my guess for combined 2 and 3

> 2 - **Working from home**
>  We're King from Home - Changing to, WOR - KING from home 
>  3 - **The devil is in the details**
>  666 or devil in D-Tails

Thoughts -

> I think one puzzle at a time would be best next time :) 
>  Plus, I think Hugh should get the check mark as two more were added after the original 1 was solved.

Comment: I believe #2 is rot13(eblnyyl cvffrq)

Comment: Post it. All your friends are doing it. :)

Comment: Point taken. Didn't want to spam the page with rebuses but editing the post repeatedly was clunky. @Avi he actually looks quite happy though

Comment: @anodyne That's because he already went to the outhouse... you should've seen his face going in.

Comment: @anodyne, Do one a day or something. Not as big a deal as you may think. People like these.

Comment: @Avi LOL. And noted, I'll do that in the future instead!

Comment: Thanks @MacGyver88 for the attempt to get 2 solved. I'll note that the king seems to be coming "from home".

Comment: @anodyne, rot13(qvq jr ona gur xvat sebz ubzr?)

Comment: @MacGyver88 nope but we're may pronounce he's from home. :)

Comment: @MacGyver88 That's it! Nice, and thanks for taking the time to complete all three solutions.

Comment: I'd suggest changing "we're" to "were" for a more universal homophone, as in a lot of places they're pronounced quite differently, making the puzzle almost impossible.

Comment: Congratulations on getting the last two! I thought about it for a bit then gave up.

Comment: @Hugh, Thanks. I just knew it had to be done to preserve completeness.